# Bixolon Auto connection Mfi iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to connect an application to Bixolon printer over Mfi. The device is already paried in iOS bluetooth to the printer. I have implemented the BXPrinterControlDelegate as part of my Appdelete.

When I call the "lookup" the method didFindPrinter is triggered several times. The devices are set as the target of the printer controller.

The methods willConnect / didNotConnect / didConnect are never being triggered.

I have set the printer controller to use autoconnect. However, when I try to print the printer is not connected ? The following status is returned "status = 103 & state = 0"

Has anyone had any luck printing with these devices before on iOS applications and have any tips on where I need to look to get the connection working ?

Comment: Does AutoConnection set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a field to your target properties.

```
key: Supported external accessory protocols 
val: com.bixolon.protocol
```

And the lookup that happens multiple times is because your setting the `lookupCount` to 5.